# How do I bind multiple classes in batman.js?

Tags: html, class, font-awesome, batman.js, dashing

I am building a Dashings dashboard and using font-awesome to display icons in a widget. I am trying to bind a dynamic class and a static class to one tag in the html such as

```
<i data-bind-class="item.icon icon-large"></i>
```

but obviously this isn't working. What is the correct way to do it so that both classes apply?

Comment: What is the reason for the dynamic class? Perhaps there is a different way to accomplish what you want without a dynamic class? You could use JS

Comment: Well the icon is changing based on what is determined to be displayed in the Ruby job. From what I understand, that is the whole purpose of the batman bindings. I just need to way to combine them. I actually think I could just set the icon in the Ruby job to something like "icon-circle icon-large" and then when it is passed up item.icon will populate it correctly. I will have to give that a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Batman's [append](http://batmanjs.org/docs/api/batman.view_filters.html#append%28value%2C_string%29_%3A_string) view filter. For example:

```
<i data-bind-class="item.icon | append ' icon-large'"></i>
```

Note that a string literal passed to `append` should be wrapped in quotes!